# Анимировать h4 с плавным возвратом обратно

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при наведении на div вложенный в него h4 должен смещаться влево, а когда убрать мышь то плавно возвращаться обратно. Начало анимации работает норм, а вот обратно резкий скачок обратно, как это можно исправить?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper h4 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}
.wrapper:hover h4 {
  -webkit-animation: head .5s;
  animation: head .5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes head {
  from {
    right: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: 35%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h4>Hello</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper h4 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  -webkit-animation: in .5s;
  animation: in .5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.wrapper:hover h4 {
  -webkit-animation: out .5s;
  animation: out .5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes in {
  from {
    right: 35%;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}
 @keyframes out {
  from {
    right: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: 35%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h4>Hello</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем две анимации для этого использовать? Одной не получается добиться такого эффекта?

Comment: можно и одной, но вопрос звучал, про плавный возврат обратно, имелось ввиду сделать функцию возврата в CSS

Comment: я не понимаю почему в этом случаи не срабатывает animation-fill-mode: forwards; поидеи должна была быть 1 анимация ну и animation-fill-mode чтобы возвращать обратно а оно не срабатывает, можете мне обьяснить почему так происходит?